# SharePoint 2013 & Visual Studio 2015 Workflow httpsend

Tags: rest, workflow-manager, workflow-variable

I am using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise version. I have already configure Workflow 2013 platform.

I am creating workflow with visual studio 2105 ultimate version. What I am doing is that I am getting current item for running workflow. Based on that item property I am filtering other list (SharePoint 2013 rest api) through `httpsend` and get data in `json` format whcih I am storing in dynamic value variable. I am getting multiple item. When I debug the workflow I can see the data.

But now issue starts here, When I am making string by looping dynamic value but I am getting empty value.

Kindly tell me what I am doing wrong. May something I am missing :(

1. Full workflow screen

[image]

2. httpsend properties

[image]

3. httpsend request headers

[image]

4. httpsend uri

[image]

5. For loop GetDynamicValueProperties variable assignment

[image]

6. For Loop String Builder, but when I write the string on history I am not getting of item, just static string is coming

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Thank to **@Shelly Coburn**. Her instruction put me in right direction. Below is the way to solve the issue.

1. After getting httpsend we will get data as

   "d" : { "results" : [] }
   So I reassign dynamic value to itself

[image]

2. Then In define properties I gave path

[image]

3. Then I use **ForEach loop** as my original question but now reassign direct properties as below

[image]

Bingo all works as I want, Many thanx `Shelly Coburn` to putting me right direction.

Hope it can help to somebody

Answer (score 3):

Before your foreach loop, assign a new dynamicValue to the d/results property of the GatePassDetailsProperties dynamicValue (or reuse and reassign the current dynamicValue).  Then, for each item, you'll be able to get Title, Nationality, JobTitle, PassportNo as the top-level property.

Also, make sure your assignments are going to variables and not the output parameters. You'll use the variables to assign the values to the output params.  The workflow design surface can be a real pain in the neck and not do what you'd expect if you try to assign to the output params directly from a GetDynamicValueProperties activity.  It does work as expected when the activity for assigning a single property is used.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Let me try this and I will inform you.

Comment: Can I get example that how can I do that or some article URL. I will be highly appreciated

Comment: Thanks I could resolve the issue as per your instruction

Comment: I'm glad I could help!